# mvvm datepicker showing null

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Finally made the move from WinForms to WPF/MVVM and things have been going very well until I hit a wall with Datepicker!

The plan is to update a database search based on the selected date and as of now I keep getting null value.

xaml

```
<DatePicker x:Name="SetDatePicker" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SetTheDate, Source={StaticResource fan}, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}" Grid.Column="0" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5"/>
```

ViewModel

```
 private DateTime? setthedate;

    public DateTime? SetTheDate
    {
        get { return setthedate; }
        set
        {
            if (setthedate != value)
            {
                setthedate = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("SetTheDate");
            }
        }
    }
```

Property that populates the Datagrid

```
public DataTable BHDT
    {
        get { return BHResults(Convert.ToDateTime(setthedate)); }
        set
        {
            if(bhdt != value)
            {
                bhdt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BHDT");
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what I am missing but from everything I have found it appears that the code is correct.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is the DatePicker displayed inside a DataGrid cell? What is "fan"? What value do you expect the DatePicker to display? Did you set the SetTheDate property to this value?

Comment: Suggest you run Snoop WPF, and inspect the data grid and date picker at runtime.  Are you getting any binding errors in your output console?

Comment: you given the model to DataContext in your xaml file?

Comment: The DatePicker is separate from the Datagrid.

Comment: @mm8 "fan" is <vm:FanCurrentVM x:Key="fan"/>

Comment: @mm8 I want the DatePicker to return the selected date and not sure what you are asking on the "Di you set the SetTheDate" property to this value

Comment: @mm8 The DatePicker itself is working fine, it loads with and displays the current date and then displays the selected date after that. When it goes through the VeiwModel portion it is correct but then when I try to use the date in BHDT it is null.

Comment: It doesn't set any date in the DataTable. It sets the SetTheDate property of the view model so I don't really understand you.

Comment: SetTheDate gives the date value to setthedate and BHDT uses setthedate when it gets the data for the DataGrid

Comment: And BHDT is in the same ViewModel

Comment: Where is the date null? Please provide a full repo of what you are talking about if you want anyone to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Use Snoop to examine your bindings and property values at runtime, it may help identify the problem.

Comment: get { return BHResults(Convert.ToDateTime(setthedate)); } At that point for some reason setthedate is null.

Comment: @mm8 Got it thank you for your time. The project so far is over 3,000 lines of code total and at one point I was declaring the VM a second time and there by returning setthedate back to null.

Answer (score 0):

**In your xaml.cs** must declare the constructor as :

```
public partial class YourFormName
    { 
     private ViewModel.YourViewModelName model;

     public YourFormName() {
         this.DataContext = model;
     }
     ...
   }
```

**in your xaml file:** (if your xaml don't work)

```
<DatePicker x:Name="SetDatePicker" SelectedValue="{Binding SetTheDate, Mode=TwoWay, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}" Grid.Column="0" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,5"/>
```

Comment: OP keeps getting `null` value which means the viewmodel is already bound to `DataContext`...

Comment: have you declared xmlns:ViewModel and xmlns:Class in your xaml header? put some breakpoints on get and set

Comment: @AlleXyS  Yes it is all declared.

Comment: @AlleXyS I have stepped through it so many times. Everything works great until I want to use "setthedate" then it goes back to "null"

Comment: even if look like that doesn't matter, try to change setthedate into setTheDate, how I know, C# is case sensitive. And in your set let only : setTheDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SetTheDate");

Comment: @AlleXyS Got it thank you for your time. The project so far is over 3,000 lines of code total and at one point I was declaring the VM a second time and there by returning setthedate back to null.